# Powershell..select drop down menu from web page

Tags: powershell, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

im trying to select a drop down menu on a website but im completely lost on how to do so. i googled the hell out of it but no luck on finding anything. this is what im trying to do..

connect to the web..
select a item from the drop down menu
set quantity
then add to cart
........................................................

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Web Link"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,150) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
   {$tag=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
   {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,75)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$WebSite=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()})
$OKButton.TabIndex=1

$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)
$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Enter Website Page:"

$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objTextBox.TabIndex = 0

$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox)
$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})

[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

#Connect to Website
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("$WebSite")
$ie.visible = $true
   while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000; }


i see this on the website, but i dont know hot to set the value or select the item. or is there easier way to
do this when the webpage loads?


#<select name="skuAndSize" class="size-dropdown mediumSelect footwear selectBox" style="display: none;">
         <option value=""></option>
            <option name="skuId" value="2870325:7"> 7</option>
            <option class="size-not-in-stock" name="skuId" value="2870326:7.5"> 7.5</option>
            <option name="skuId" value="2870327:8"> 8</option>
            <option class="size-not-in-stock" name="skuId" value="2870328:8.5"> 8.5</option>
            <option name="skuId" value="2870329:9"> 9</option>
            <option name="skuId" value="2870330:9.5"> 9.5</option>
            <option name="skuId" value="2870331:10"> 10</option>
            <option class="size-not-in-stock" name="skuId" value="2870332:10.5"> 10.5</option>
            <option name="skuId" value="2870333:11"> 11</option>
            <option class="size-not-in-stock" name="skuId" value="2870334:11.5"> 11.5</option>
            <option name="skuId" value="2870335:12"> 12</option>
            <option class="size-not-in-stock" name="skuId" value="2870336:12.5"> 12.5</option>
            <option name="skuId" value="2870337:13"> 13</option>
            <option class="size-not-in-stock" name="skuId" value="2870338:13.5"> 13.5</option>
            <option name="skuId" value="2870339:14"> 14</option>
            <option class="size-not-in-stock" name="skuId" value="2870340:15"> 15</option>
            <option class="size-not-in-stock" name="skuId" value="2870341:16"> 16</option>
            <option class="size-not-in-stock" name="skuId" value="2870342:17"> 17</option>
            <option class="size-not-in-stock" name="skuId" value="2870343:18"> 18</option>
       </select> 

#<span class="selectBox-label" data-qa="pdp.buyingtools.size-dropdown">(9.5)</span>#
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
# will select item with label 9
$dropdown = $ie.Document.getElementById("skuAndSize")
($dropdown | where {$_.innerHTML -eq "9"}).Selected = $true
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a better solution which will select the value with exact text

**Define a function**

> applicationList is the id of the select tag
>
> test abc is the exact text to match

---

```
function Subscription()
{
$x = $IE.document.getElementById("applicationList");
for($i=0;$i -lt $x.length;$i++)
{
If($x.options[$i].text -eq "test abc")
{
return $i;
}}}
```

**Call the Function**

```
$index=Subscription;
$IE.Document.getElementById("applicationList").SelectedIndex=$index;
```