# select option by text in webform

Tags: powershell, drop-down-menu, webforms, powershell-2.0

I'm using powershell for completing webform. I have dropdown there and can select it by value:

```
$dropdown.value = '3236'
```

It works fine, but I need to select by text. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15158136/240564) and tried this code:

```
($dropdown | where {$_.innerHTML -eq "sometext"}).Selected = $true
```

It works too, but because dropdown has too many options (probably several thousands), it takes several minutes to select, which is not acceptable.

How can I improve this?

btw, I use powershell 2.0

Comment: Maybe I'm completely wrong, as I have no idea how to do it yet, but I'm looking for other purposes: You should be able to use Lucene.NET (https://lucenenet.apache.org/) to parse your values, right?

Comment: should I use Licence from my .NET application? Unfortunately I can use only Powershell here.

Comment: maybe I can map values and text using powershell?

Comment: I'm definitely a beginner at powershell and just scratching the surface of .NET fundamentals but if I got it right you should be able to use most if not all .Net librairies in PS. So, again theoratically because I'm still trying to figure it out myself, you could load your innerHTML code in the lucene library to parse it for the value you look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found solution, maybe it isn't perfect, but I got performance improved in hundreds times, instead several minutes it takes less than second.

I created the following function:

```
function getValue($innerHTML, $Name)
{    
    $innerHTML = $innerHTML.Substring($innerHTML.IndexOf($Name) - 11, 10)        
    return $innerHTML.Substring($innerHTML.IndexOf('=') + 1)
}
```

Function takes innerHTML of dropdown as string, search for option name and return value instead.

and use function the following way:

```
$drop.Value = getValue $drop.innerHTML 'somename'
```